# How to send values of expression language?

Tags: java, servlets

The expression language contains names of places and whichever link the user presses I am supposed to display the info of that place.

I've displayed the links using the following code:

```
<c:forEach items="${places}" var="p">    
     <a href="showPlaceInfo.user">${p.name}</a>
</c:forEach>
```

How am I supposed to get the place name so that i can display the place info?

Comment: Send it as a request parameter `<a href="showPlaceInfo.user?place=$p.name">${p.name}</a>`. Although I'm not overly convinced that `showPlaceInfo.user` is a valid URL - did you mean `${showPlaceInfo.user}`? And even then, it's relative; which is a big nono.

Comment: @BoristheSpider  Thanks...I got the value as request parameter by doing this:  `showPlaceInfo.user?place=${p.name}` inside the href